# How to change a specific row inside a json file using counter +1

Tags: json, curl

I would like to add a new user each time I run the Curl command. I need the code to be able to use the same details, but to advance the email counter by 1: `newmail1@mail.com, newmail2@mail.com, newmail3@mail.com...`

The curl command I use is:

```
curl -d "@newuser.json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://mywebsite
```

The `newuser.json` file looks like this:

```
{
"email": "newuser1@mail.com",
"firstName": "firstName",
"lastName": "lastName",
"gender": "male",
"language":"English",
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your question. Curl invokes a service, and passes a request body, or receives a response body. It is up to your code to provide the expected JSON data. Curl takes what you pass to it, or what that service returns.  Beyond that: there is no "counter" in your example. Thus: no idea what you are asking about.

Comment: On windows you can use its old JS script engine and set it by simple JavaScript or anywhere by node.js if you have it installed. But with node.js you do not need even curl and can make also your request by same script. Or you can try to create JSON by for, echo-s, etc. in batch file (ugly) or by shell script in Linux, but also not good idea. JavaScript is most straightforward and easiest language for JSON operations as JSON is native and came from there.